# Can pssh execute command on the control machine?

Tags: ssh

Can pssh parallelly execute commands on a control machine?

Now I have three machines.

> This is my `hostpssh` file. They are corresponding to `druidcluster1`, `druidcluster2`, `druidcluster4`.

```
root@9.116.2.59
root@9.116.2.70
root@9.116.2.254
```

ssh mutual trust are all established, include ssh trust to each machine itself:

```
[root@druidcluster1 generalsoftware]# ssh druidcluster1 date
Sun May 12 02:02:49 CDT 2019
[root@druidcluster1 generalsoftware]# ssh druidcluster2 date
Sun May 12 02:02:55 CDT 2019
[root@druidcluster1 generalsoftware]# ssh druidcluster4 date
Sun May 12 02:03:01 CDT 2019

[root@druidcluster2 .ssh]# ssh druidcluster2 date
Sun May 12 02:02:19 CDT 2019
[root@druidcluster2 .ssh]# ssh druidcluster1 date
Sun May 12 02:02:25 CDT 2019
[root@druidcluster2 .ssh]# ssh druidcluster4 date
Sun May 12 02:02:31 CDT 2019

[root@druidcluster4 .ssh]# ssh druidcluster4 date
Sun May 12 02:02:01 CDT 2019
[root@druidcluster4 .ssh]# ssh druidcluster1 date
Sun May 12 02:02:08 CDT 2019
[root@druidcluster4 .ssh]# ssh druidcluster2 date
Sun May 12 02:02:14 CDT 2019
```

Then I execute `pssh -h hostpssh -P date` on `druidcluster1` and get:

```
[root@druidcluster1 generalsoftware]# pssh -h hostpssh -P date
[1] 01:33:34 [FAILURE] root@9.116.2.59 Exited with error code 255
9.116.2.254: Sun May 12 01:33:37 CDT 2019
[2] 01:33:37 [SUCCESS] root@9.116.2.254
9.116.2.70: Sun May 12 01:33:37 CDT 2019
[3] 01:33:37 [SUCCESS] root@9.116.2.70
```

Only the command on the control machine failed.

Comment: This issue is solved. The conclustion is that: **pssh can execute command on the control machine**. The reason why I failed at the time of asking this question is that: there are two ip's in my virtual machine, one (10.x.x.x) for internal and the other one (9.x.x.x) for external. When I established ssh mutual trust with **hostname**, other external machines map hostname to 9.x.x.x but the control machine itself maps hostname to 10.x.x.x. So the main reason is still the unsuccessful ssh mutual trust.